# Execute command on multiple files matching a pattern in parallel

Tags: command-line, parallelism

Let's say I have a command accepting a single argument which is a file path:

```
mycommand myfile.txt
```

Now I want to execute this command over multiple files in parallel, more specifically, file matching pattern `myfile*`.

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Comment: You could use find for that, something like `find . -name "*xls*" -exec ls -l {} \;`. In your case: `find . -name "*xls*" -exec mycommand  {} \;`. Although find searches for files recursively you can limit `find` not to search in all sub directories.

Comment: that would run the commands sequentially, not in parallel

Comment: Oh, ok, sorry, right. I didn't get this point.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With GNU `xargs` and a shell with support for process substitution

```
xargs -r -0 -P4 -n1 -a <(printf '%s\0' myfile*) mycommand
```

Would run up to 4 `mycommand`s in parallel.

If `mycommand` doesn't use its stdin, you can also do:

```
printf '%s\0' myfile* | xargs -r -0 -P4 -n1 mycommand
```

Which would also work with the `xargs` of modern BSDs.

For a recursive search for `myfile*` files, replace the `printf` command with:

```
find . -name 'myfile*' -type f -print0
```

(`-type f` is for regular-files only. For a glob-equivalent, you need `zsh` and its `printf '%s\0' myfile*(.)`).

Comment: Is the benefit of this - over a loop - that the `xargs -0` and `printf "%s\0"` combination handle whitespace in the filenames better?

Comment: @the_velour_fog, no the loop will handle whitespace OK as long as you don't forget to quote the variables. The benefit is that you can limit the number of concurrent processes more easily and that you can handle `find`'s output more easily.

Answer (score 7):

Using a loop:

```
for f in myfile*; do
  mycommand "$f" &
done

wait
```

or using [GNU parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/).

Answer (score 4):

Using GNU Parallel it looks like this:

```
parallel mycommand ::: myfile*
```

It will run one job per core.

GNU Parallel is a general parallelizer and makes is easy to run jobs in parallel on the same machine or on multiple machines you have ssh access to. It can often replace a `for` loop.

If you have 32 different jobs you want to run on 4 CPUs, a straight forward way to parallelize is to run 8 jobs on each CPU:

[image: Simple scheduling]

GNU Parallel instead spawns a new process when one finishes - keeping the CPUs active and thus saving time:

[image: GNU Parallel scheduling]

**Installation**

If GNU Parallel is not packaged for your distribution, you can do a personal installation, which does not require root access. It can be done in 10 seconds by doing this:

```
(wget -O - pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/ || fetch -o - http://pi.dk/3) | bash
```

For other installation options see http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/README

**Learn more**

See more examples: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html

Watch the intro videos: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Walk through the tutorial: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html

Sign up for the email list to get support: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/parallel