# Execute command on multiple severs in parallel using shell script

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell

I have 1000s of remote machines. I want to run some specific commands on all of them, but in parallel.
I use these commands which run sequentially:

```
for f in `cat host.lst`
do
       ./runScript.sh $f
done
```

Let's suppose `host.lst` contains 100 hosts.  I want to run `runScript.sh` on 100 hosts in parallel. Also, logs should be maintained.

I can not install any utility on my machine such as `PSSH`.

I have done a lot of research and found these links but they did not help. I do not understand how they work:

[Automatically run commands over SSH on many servers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19008/automatically-run-commands-over-ssh-on-many-servers)

[Execute command on multiple files matching a pattern in parallel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/265703/execute-command-on-multiple-files-matching-a-pattern-in-parallel)

Can any one explain the logic?

Comment: There are answers in both the questions that you referenced that don't require pssh. Some use GNU parallel (which would be my choice) but there are others that use only commands that are commonly installed on Unix-like systems. I'd advise that you [edit] the question to show which of those answers you've tried and detail the problems you encountered. As it stands, this question is a duplicate.

Comment: See if you understand https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html#Remote-execution You do not need to be root to use GNU Parallel - even if it is not installed: http://oletange.blogspot.dk/2013/04/why-not-install-gnu-parallel.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
logdir=`mktemp -d`
bunch=200

IFS=$'\n'
for hosts in $(< hosts.lst xargs -r -L "$bunch"); do
   IFS=" ";
   for host in $hosts; do
      ssh -n -o BatchMode=yes "$host" './runScript.sh' 1>"$logdir/$host.log" 2>&1 &
   done
   wait
done
```

Assuming the 1000s (thousands) of hosts are listed one/line in the `hosts.lst` file and then from these a bunch are selected in one time (200), and on each of these 200 hosts are spawned your `runScript.sh` using `ssh` in `batch mode` and at the same time preserving the `stdout+stderr` spewing forth from each of these backgrounded job into a file with the name of `host` in the directory `$logdir`, which may be examined as and when required.

Finally we wait for one bunch to get over before we launch the next bunch, by means of the `wait` command at the end of the inner `for` loop.

Comment: Rakesh, i think you were trying to write 1000s ???? u wrote 100s.

Comment: I just want to trigger the runscript only.  so can " ssh -n -o Batch mode=yes "$host"  " can be removed??

Comment: what do you mean trigger runscript.sh? If you want to remve ssh then why bother about that hosts list ?

Comment: sorry "$host" is needed  runscript.sh will take care of every thing like **scp, rsync** and all. I just need to trigger runscript.sh.

Comment: Thanks Rakesh, It worked !! last question, Can i use exec in place of xargs?? What would be the impact..

Comment: I don't think `exec` is the appropriate tool in this scenario as `exec` replaces it's parent by itself. `xargs` can be useful if your version supports the `-P` flag.

Answer (score 2):

The following modification to your script, which doesn't require any other utilities, will execute in parallel, but may run into limits depending on your hosts' limitations of open file handles:

```
for f in $(cat host.lst); do
       ./runScript.sh $f &
done
```

To capture the results to a log, just add `> run.log` after `done` to save to a new file, `run.log`.

The key change is the addition of `&`, which runs a process in the background rather than waiting for it to complete before executing the next command.

Comment: If the count is high in list suppose 1000, then it should pick the 200 one time..Because changing the list of host again will lead to manual task.

Comment: you could use `split` to divvy up the list into batches, and do each batch in parallel.

Comment: in that case i have to maintain 10 for loop ( 10 batches).